# How do I change Google Chrome's change tab shortcut to be like Unix?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, keyboard, documentation, shortcut

*I have tried the shortcut manager extension to no avail.* I have recently found out about adding App Shortcuts with Keyboard. Keyboard asks me to provide it with the Application for which I am providing a shortcut, the name of the menu command that I want to make a shortcut for, and the shortcut.
[image: The confusing menu]

Menu title reads: Enter the exact name of the menu command you want to add. Looking further into this, Apple Support says: "You must type the command exactly as it appears in the application menu, including ellipses and any other punctuation."

How do I find the application menu for Chrome? I have tried typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> or "Switches to the next tab" in the menu title field and replaced it with my preferred way to switch tabs (like a Unix Shell) to no avail.

Comment: Could you be more precise ? You want to switch tab using Ctrl + Tab ?

Comment: I want to be able to switch tabs using command + shift + right/left @Samoth

Comment: I'm kind of disappointed because I try your description using the menu title in my language and it words perfectly...

Comment: You are able to switch tabs using command + shift+ right/left? What did you put in the menu title field? @Samoth

Comment: I just wrote the corresponding menu (can't tell you the exact, mine is not English) in the `menu title` case

Comment: How did you find the menu title? @Samoth

Comment: Open `chrome`, menu `window` and this should be something like `Select the next tab`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrote the corresponding menu (can't tell you the exact, mine is not English) in the `menu title` case. To find the name of the menu, open chrome => menu window and this should be something like `Select the next tab`